# String Manipulation: join with comma

Tags: elixir, ets

How can I get below string as result from the way i am getting it right now in elixir.

```
['x1', 'x2']
```

I tried with `enum.join` but did not get the desired data

to

```
'x1,x2'
```

Comment: what is the input and what is the expected output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you should use [`Enum.join/2`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Enum.html#join/2) with the second parameter to define the "joiner". this should work:

```
arr = ['x1', 'x2']
Enum.join(arr, ",")
# => "x1,x2"
```

If you want the result to be char list, you can turn it to one using [`String.to_char_list/1`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/String.html#to_char_list/1):

```
String.to_char_list(Enum.join(arr, ","))
# => 'x1,x2'
```

Another option is to use [`Enum.reduce/2`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/2) and add the joiner explicitly:

```
Enum.reduce(arr, &(&2 ++ ',' ++ &1))               
# => 'x1,x2'
```

Comment: Exactly, i did but its returning the double quotes and not single quotes, looking to get the data in form as 'x1,x2'

Answer (score 2):

Here's a classic recursive implementation of `join` for single quoted strings:

```
defmodule MyString do
  def join(list, joiner \\ ''), do: do_join(list, joiner)
  defp do_join([], joiner), do: ''
  defp do_join([hd], joiner), do: hd
  defp do_join([hd | tl], joiner), do: hd ++ joiner ++ join(tl, joiner)
end

iex> MyString.join([], ',')
[]

iex> MyString.join(['x1'], ',')
'x1'

iex> MyString.join(['x1', 'x2'], ',')
'x1,x2'

iex> MyString.join(['x1', 'x2'])
'x1x2'
```